# White flickering animation when presenting modally

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tvos

Hello I prepared simple tvOS project, where I present view controller modally. I'm receiving fade animation with white flickering (see below) while presenting view controller modally. How can I remove the flickering?

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    @IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Animation I receive:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the outgoing view is having its alpha animated to zero, which means that the wallpaper image behind it may be starting to show through a bit before the incoming view has animated its alpha in enough to cover it up.

Is this a custom presentation animation? Can you adjust the way the alpha on the outgoing view is changed?

Comment: Actually that was a good point. I figured that out during the transition between source and destination both of them are transparent, so background color from root window appears on the screen. All I had to do was to put background color to be black.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the flickering animation change animated to false.

Code:

```
present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I want to keep that animation. A fade animation between black and dark red.

Comment: To make a fade check this resource: https://www.raywenderlich.com/359-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions